# SimpleHTTPServer not found python3

Tags: python, http, server, httpserver, simplehttpserver

I'm trying to write a simple server in python. So after watching tutorial, I'm trying to import a few modules.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer
from http.server import SimpleHTTPServer
```

[As the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer) says, it has been moved, that's why i'm doing so.

But it gives me this error : **from http.server import SimpleHTTPServer
ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleHTTPServer'**

And without `SimpleHTTPServer` I can't use `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`, as it is defined in `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`.

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: The `SimpleHTTPServer` was moved to *be* the module `http.server`. You want to use the request handler class `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).

Comment: If you're using Python 3 it's probably best to refer to _those_ docs, not the ones for Python 2.

Comment: thanks.. it worked ... you should post it as answer.. @rassar

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `SimpleHTTPServer` module was moved to *be* the module [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html). So the command is:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Also, the new `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` object is `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was:

```
python -m http.server
```

If I type `python3` on the console is printed "Python not found".
(I'm on Windows)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).